# Tower Property with Filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a filtered probability space: $(\Omega,F,\{F_t\}_{t\geq0},P)$.

For any $0\leq s<t$ and stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$, we have the following Tower property:

$E(E(X|F_t)|F_s)=E(X|F_s)$.

If we treat the filtration as an information set, why is it that the smaller information set "wins" the bigger information?

For example, consider the following example of voting count in an election. If $X_t$ represents the candidate $X$'s vote counts at time $t$ and the filtrations represent the information available, the RHS tells me it is the expectation of the candidate $X$ vote count with say 4 hours in (i.e. $s=4$). If $t=12$, so $F_t$ is the information available on the voting 12 hours in, shouldn't the inside of the iterated conditional actually "win" the smaller information, $F_s$? If we make a prediction on average the candidate will acquire this number of votes, then making another prediction based on the less comprehensive past information shouldn't "cancel out" more accurate resolution of information I have already in hand, no?

Where is my intuition going wrong?

Comment: I don't see how this is a "win" for $F_S$. If anything, it tells you that $F_t$ contains the info of $F_S$.

Comment: @DonThousand Hi Don, can you please elaborate? thanks

Comment: You can't tell what the result will be 12 hours in when you are only 4 hours in, unless the count is finished by the 4 hour mark.

Comment: @user10354138 Ok this is great. So it sounds like you are referring to the LHS. How would you read the LHS then?

Comment: The LHS is "the best prediction at time $s$ of what the best prediction at time $t$ of $X$ would be".  In your example: at time $s$ (i.e. 4 hours into the count), if you are predicting (or expecting, same thing) that you will predict/expect (whatever the count is going to be) at time $t>s$ (i.e., in another 8 hours time), then you are already predicting it at time $s$.